# Filtering out redundant repeated data from a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks a like this;

```
index, othercols, FPN
ts1, otherStuff, val1
ts2, otherStuff, val2
ts3, otherStuff, val3
ts4, otherStuff, val4
....
tsn, otherStuff, valn
```

Because of the external data source a lot of these values will be repeated- so in million row dataframe there will be several pieces up to 10,000s entries long all just repeating the same data for concurrent timestamps. For my purposes at least this repetition is not necessary, so I want to remove all the repeated rows apart from the beginning and end of each section like so;

```
1, 0
2, 0
3, 0
4, 5
5, 0
6, 0
```

becomes

```
1, 0 
3, 0
4, 5
5, 0
6, 0
```

I have managed to do this, but it's slower than I would like (takes 2 mins for a single 60mb file; mostly in the apply part as seen below) and I'm thinking that there must be a better way of doing it

Here's my cobbled together solution, is there a neater/faster way of doing this?;

```
data=df['FPN']

shft_up=(copy.deepcopy(data)).tolist()
shft_dn=(copy.deepcopy(data)).tolist()

del shft_up[0]
shft_up=shft_up+[None]

del shft_dn[-1]
shft_dn=[None]+shft_dn

df['shft_up']=shft_up
df['shft_dn']=shft_dn

def is_rep(row):
    if row['shft_dn']==row['FPN'] and row['shft_up']==row['FPN']:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0  

df['mask_col']=df.apply(lambda row:is_rep(row),axis=1,reduce=False)

df=(df[df['mask_col']==0]).drop(['shft_up','shft_dn','mask_col'],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have this logic correct, I add a new column 'run' which is a boolean to say whether the value is the same as the previous row's value:

```
In [438]:

df['run'] = (df['val'] == df['val'].shift())
df
Out[438]:
   id  val    run
0   1    0  False
1   2    0   True
2   3    0   True
3   4    5  False
4   5    0  False
5   6    0   True
```

I then filter out the values where run is `True` and the next row is also `True`:

```
In [442]:

df[~((df['run']==True) & (df['run'].shift(-1) == True))]
Out[442]:
   id  val    run
0   1    0  False
2   3    0   True
3   4    5  False
4   5    0  False
5   6    0   True
```

**EDIT**

The following one-liner also works just to confirm to the OP:

```
In [447]:

df = df[(df['val'].shift()!=df['val'].shift(-1)) | (df['val']!=df['val'].shift(-1))]
df
Out[447]:
   id  val
0   1    0
2   3    0
3   4    5
4   5    0
5   6    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you can actually use this method in just one line;

df = df[(df['FPN'].shift()!=df['FPN'].shift(-1)) | (df['FPN']!=df['FPN'].shift(-1))]

either way it's about an order of magnitude faster and many less lines than my first stab.